# Questions about really rare languages

Tags: discussion, questions, languages

I have recently noticed [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27894684/2930268), which seems to be about a programming language called MJS (and, more recently, MJSLQ).

It seems from the comments that a lot of people do not know what this language is. The question is currently tagged under java, javascript, and html tags, and stackoverflow does not have an MJS tag.

I have searched Google for MJS and MJSLQ, but I cannot find any results about this programming language.

So, I am intrigued as to why there are questions about languages that nobody seems to know about.

Comment: Well, if Google can't help you, where else can you turn to besides Stack Overflow?

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom, I agree. This does make sense.

Comment: Perhaps there should be an "other language" tag for questions that are programming language specific but whose language does not yet have a tag. People who are generally interested in programming languages could monitor it, and possibly help rare language users.

Comment: Good idea. But should MJS have its own tag?

Comment: It sounds too much like 'MySQL' to be any good :)

Comment: Maybe it's a custom macro-language made for some entreprise software.

Comment: One of the modules for my university degree used to ask you to make your own programming language (write compilers etc), so therefore I'm sure there are an infinite number of languages SO doesn't know about... The OP has probably come to SO before for other programming help

Comment: @Sayse - well, asking how to solve a pretty specific programming issue in a language you yourself created and that noone else has ever seen before, seems a tad optimistic. I call bullshit, no such programming language exists, and VarhoonMangyk has asked the only two questions in existance, so I'm guessing it's a typo or a troll. I was thinking JMS/JMSQ, but the syntax doesn't really match that either, but at least ArrayList would exist (`util.ArrayList`) ?

Comment: @adeneo  - I didn't mean to imply that he was asking for help debugging code in his own language but that there are a multitude of languages around that the OP could have got a hold of. More likely its a company specific language implementation method

Comment: @Sayse - who knows what it is, but whatever it is, it's not java, javascript and HTML all at the same time, and the syntax in the posted code is strange, to say the least, and even if it was an obscure language for internal company use or whatever, it's even stranger that no matches exists on Google etc. Seems more like the OP is confused.

Comment: Maybe it's some custom language a professor invented for his research (and is now confusing his poor students with). Here's a dude who's initials are MJS: http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~mjs/. A couple of his courses come up if you search for "mjs arraylist". Here's something about "MJS assignments": https://code.google.com/p/mjs-coding-assignments/source/browse/trunk/src/main/Parser.java?r=5.

Comment: There's also Mono JScript, which is dead to consider: http://www.mono-project.com/archived/jscript/.

Comment: I'm just waiting for the [Hoon](http://doc.urbit.org/doc/hoon/tut/1/) questions to appear.

Comment: The syntax reminds me of [BobX](http://thedailywtf.com/articles/We-Use-BobX)

Comment: The language may exist for the purpose of **not** having experts on-line who will answer programming assignment questions in it. That forces the students to actually do the assignments, rather than making an attempt and asking SO as soon as it gets difficult.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan: I think assignments should encourage students to find solutions on the internet, because that's pretty much what happens in a real job when you don't know how to do something

Comment: @musefan Maybe the professor is trying to prepare the students to be able to be the one who first works out how to do something, rather than limiting them to be followers who can only do things somebody else has worked out before them.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan: I dunno, I think that kind of intelligence comes from an early age. You either have it or you don't, not something to be taught.

Comment: I have to agree that I don't think it's a great idea. The lesson taught here is that you shouldn't ask for help when you get stuck, which simply isn't true. I get that you don't want people getting the work done for them, but stopping that at the cost of also destroying the valid workflow of 'Attempt -> Fail -> Get Help -> Learn -> Succeed' is bad. It makes sense for a test where you want to check if the student understands something, but if you want them to learn, then the aim is simply to get them to think about the solution enough to learn it, which is only impeded by this technique.

Comment: Maybe we should have #exotic-languages tag?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Well, Varhoon Mangyk explained what MJS is in the comments to his question.

> @DnR, I am very sorry for my stupid mistake. MJS and MJSLQ wturned out to be languages created by my cs teacher. Exactly as Patricia Shanahan has said in the meta-post, ` The language may exist for the purpose of not having experts on-line who will answer programming assignment questions in it. That forces the students to actually do the assignments, rather than making an attempt and asking SO as soon as it gets difficult.

Comment: But what if the professor re-uses this language, and next year we get another `MJS` question?

Comment: The only expert on MJS would be the inventor and possibly any people who take the class. I don't think it's necessary to have a tag for it. Unlike my Karel example, this appears to be a more localized language that will probably never grow outside the realm of that university, and probably impractical as a language for kids to learn. The best place to ask for support would likely be from the professor or prior students.

Comment: @Compass, agreed.

Comment: One of my CS professors invented his own language.  It [has a Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SALSA_%28programming_language%29)... somehow.

Comment: Off-topic, but in a way I think its great that these questions are appearing on SO, it defeats his logic of stopping people using SO as a resource. (Also, I don't agree with his methods since university is supposed to prepare you for real world programming)

Comment: @Sayse so long as the language is complete it should teach the concepts as well as any other language.  If you know how to program, learning a new language should be easy.  Disagree completely that University should (or does) prepare anyone for real-world anything - that's what trade and technical schools are for.  Shame that an entire generation was sold the lie that University is some sort of preparation for the world... it's not, nor has it ever been.

Comment: @Sayse: At a technical school you learn to use language X (and maybe Y), at a university you learn the concepts behind programming languages so that you can quickly grok any language built with those concepts.

Comment: I would like to point out that this answer only applies to "private" languages.  There could be "public" languages that are still obscure and could deserve to be handled differently.

Answer (score 18):

Doing some digging, I see example code from Google Code under mjs-coding-assignments: https://code.google.com/p/mjs-coding-assignments/source/browse/trunk/src/main/Parser.java?r=5

There is also a CS professor at Carnegie Mellon who is initialled MJS: http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~mjs/.

I would posit that this is someone who is having troubles with homework and doesn't realize the MJS class is a special class made by a professor.

Answer (score 7):

> So, I am intrigued as to why there are questions about languages that
>   nobody seems to know about.

It seems there is somebody know something about that languages that's why that questions are exist.  So if anybody searches something about that language, Stackoverflow will appears. May get answers.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you and Jeffery Bosboom. Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

Whether or not a language deserves a tag should be related whether or not people actually know about it and can be experts on it. If there are no "experts" on `mjs`, a tag for it really doesn't attract any help.

A similar (though likely somewhat less obscure) language tag that I expect only a minority of SO users would know about is [karel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/karel).

Storytime: I ended up learning Karel at a summer camp in 1995 at the ripe old age of 8 and forgot its existence until it came up a few months ago on SO... in my Java feed of all things.

I find it unlikely that anyone at all is using Karel in its original form anymore (it was some sort of standalone application, or possibly Karel++ when I used it.) Now, it's basically a Java or C++ API, and, due to its use as an introductory tool for programming, likely to only be used at Stanford, where it was created, or for students at an age level probably too low to be Stack Overflow users.

The few questions that we have gotten all appear to be interpretation issues related to the language it is being used in, rather than actual questions about Karel. That being said, the people who have learned Karel are likely to be proficient enough at Karel to be considered experts (Karel only has 5 methods/actions/instructions).

Answer (score 2):

If it does not become clear what language the question deals with (either by just looking at the code or by the tags) ask the questioner. At least he/she should know. If he/she doesn't answer, downvote.

If the language is finally known but rare and you happen to not know it, do not answer the question.

Should questions about rare languages stay on SO? Yes, why not. Even they can become more popular one day. Not sure how to tag them though. Do they deserve their own tag or is a generic 'rare/exotic language' tag enough?

Finally, if there is actually no reference on google at all, we might ask the asker to prove this is not actually a fake, i.e. by asking for references to the existence of this language. I feel SO should only deal with existing languages.

Comment: What would you consider an "existing language"?

Comment: @01 I would say: a language that is used to solve interesting problems by various people all over the world for quite some time and having already been published somewhere on the internet. I meant it here in opposition to something someone has just invented to play tricks on SO answerers. To make it more concrete: I'm happy to answer every question to any language that has already been published elsewhere if I can.

Answer (score 1):

Are we sure this isn't either

a) A troll or

b) Not actually a language, but some obscure plugin for either java (or javascript, who knows based on the questions' copious use of tags?) called MJS?

Doing a google search for "MJS-ArrayList" (with quotes) yields a whopping **4** results, 2 are from SO, and the other 2 are sites which are probably aggregating SO since the content is identical:

http://exchange.opcartstore.com/questions/view/18784/mjs-array-to-arraylist?order=newest&page=2

and

https://tersee.com/#!q=myarray&t=text

the second site is just a generic landing page, but the `<meta description>` mentions the MJS-ArrayList

If "MJS-ArrayList" is actually a valid piece of syntax, which the SO questions seem to indicate that it is, don't you think google might have more than **4** entire results about it?

I think that it is actually a great idea to have some sort of "other language" tag, but I don't think that is what is happening in this particular situation

**If** you disagree, can you please find any mention of MJS anywhere?

Comment: I was going for your (b) but further Googling for keywords "arraylist" "createnew" "castto" lead to ... *nothing* (useful, to be precise). And look at the syntax! My money is going to be on (a): a troll.

Comment: although `new_memory_object` returns http://web.mit.edu/darwin/src/modules/xnu/osfmk/man/memory_object_create.html

Comment: @Jongware Turns out it's a language specifically written for homework problems so that students can't get help online.

Answer (score 1):

it looks like some sort of Java wrapper or API probably used at Universities as mentioned above Google Java MJS and it will return results from universities and coursework tasks

Comment: The syntax looks nothing like Java so it is not a custom class. None of the keywords appear in the MIT pages -- even though they contain some examples. At least the keywords ought to appear in the source code, wouldn't they? Unless this is for a *real* advanced semester on reverse engineering obfuscated code ... and if so, that fact itself is obfuscated as well.

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite see the point of your question.

I see in this case it turns out that it is a language created by a college professor. I don't see any explanation of why he decided to create this language and give his students assignments in it, other than the speculation that it was so students couldn't find answers on the Internet, but that appears to just be speculation. It seems to me to be rather unproductive to teach students a language that they will never use outside the classroom, a lot of effort devoted to learning something they will never use, but without knowing more about the class and what the professor is trying to accomplish, I'm just speculating too.

There are lots of obscure languages out there created as experimental projects and the like. I'm sure there are plenty of languages in existence that I've never heard of.

I'm suddenly reminded that I once took a computer class that used the language CARDIAC. You've probably never heard of it. It was a super-simplified machine language with just 10 op-codes. The idea was that it was easier to learn than a real machine language, but would teach the basic principles. THEN you could go on to learn a real machine language.

So ... if someone asks a question about an obscure language that only 20 people in the world have ever used, I suppose the chance that he'll get an answer here is small. But so what? Do you want to not allow him to ask? Why not? I think the whole value of a site like this is that there is some hope of getting an answer to an obscure question. If there are 10 million people in the world who know the answer to a question, I can probably find it in some reference source, "Java for Beginners" or whatever. It's the obscure questions where you need experts who can say, Oh yeah, I came across that same weird problem once ...

Comment: what if there is no publicly available documentation for Q&A readers to verify quality of content. "- Q: How do I multiply x by y in HaSQL? - A: Oh, you just call `hasql.divide(x, y)`" - is there a chance for readers to tell if the answer given is right or wrong? [Tree, falls, forest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/If_a_tree_falls_in_a_forest)

Comment: Hmm, when I get an answer to a question on Stackoverflow, I don't then try to find another source to confirm it. If I knew another source that had the answer, I would just go to that other source to begin with. Rather, I try the answer in the program (or web page or whatever) that I'm working on and see if it works. If it does, it must be right. Surely a site like Stackoverflow is, by definition, most valuable when you CANNOT find any other source for the desired information. If we only allow questions on this site where the answer is already available someone else on the Internet, why bother?

Comment: no it's not about it. Java (Haskell, SQL, MUMPS etc...) documentation is publicly available but this doesn't mean it answers all the questions. It only allows readers to verify correctness of the answers given to the question. "- Q: How do I multiply x by y in Java? - A: Oh, you just call `x/y`" -- anyone can refer language spec and tell that answer is wrong. When this is not possible, there is no way to publicly rate content - meaning no way to indicate to site visitors whether it's useful or not

Comment: But, sure there is. You try it in your program and see if it works. Suppose someone asked, "How do I multiply x by y in Foobar?" Someone replies, "You write, x $$ y". So I write a test program where I output the result of 4 $$ 7. It prints 32. Clearly the answer is wrong. If it prints 28, I'd say there's a good chance the answer is right. In any case, who said that a question should not be allowed if there is no alternative source that one could go to to "rate" the validity of the content? If that's a rule in the site rules somewhere, I think it's a foolish rule that should be repealed.

Comment: in order for one to be able to test x $$ y in Foobar (and, which is probably most important, share their results for public review / content rating), Foobar should be publicly available somehow - as a specification, or as programming environment etc. Saying "voting this answer down because it is wrong: I get 32 instead of 28" would be useless if other readers could not check that too

Comment: Well, maybe we've both expressed our opinion and further conversation would just be repetitive. But if I wasn't clear, let me put it this way: As I see it, the purpose of this site is to give people answers to practical questions. If someone doesn't have a copy of a Foobar compiler, why would they care how you multiply in Foobar? Well, maybe some academic interest, but fine, then get a copy. If you can't find one, post a question asking where to find a copy. You keep saying that answers must be verifiable from some second source. I say, who cares? If someone gives me an answer and it ...

Comment: ... works, I don't care whether I can find some other source that would give me the same answer. If this was an academic site, where we were discussing history or literature, I could at least comprehend saying that you don't want to take a poster's word for it, but want some independent confirmation. But for a software development problem, if you try it and it works, the answer is confirmed. If someone gave me an answer that proved to work, and then I found a book or a website that said that it wouldn't work, I'd conclude the book must be wrong, because I just tried it and it worked.

Comment: well, as long as that imaginary "question asking where to find a copy" is _answerable_, I am with you really. It's not critically important for one to have a copy, it's important that there is an opportunity to get a copy. Speaking of that "MJS language" asked about in this question, if it's only in the head of professor and on few student's desktops, questions about it would belong rather to university forum than to Stack Exchange - because there would be no way to reliably rate content posted here

Comment: I initially learnt most of my programming on a series of languages in college some which I could now use if I wished (LISP and PROLOG) but are not in everyday use and primarily POP-11 which I have not used since the day I left college.  I never felt it was wasted effort.  Programming is about concepts not syntax.