# What languages can I ask about on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, scope

Am I allowed to ask about any programming language, or is there a list of allowed and forbidden languages?

Comment: PHP, jQuery and SQL are all banned.

Comment: Is there a particular language you want to know about? It's worth looking at the [tags](http://stackoverflow.com/tags) to see what activity related to the language is already happening.

Comment: @MartinJames That's wrong! Everyone knows that [Stack Overflow loves jQuery](http://i.stack.imgur.com/sGhaO.gif).

Comment: Related: [Questions about really rare languages](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/283229/1591669)

Comment: @MartinJames jquery is not a language! Sorry, I had to :P (Yes I'm that guy at parties)

Comment: Pretty much any language at all as long as the question doesn't equate to _gimme the codez_ or _please do my homework for me_.

Comment: Try asking [Golfscript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/)

Comment: You can't ask any C++ questions.  If you try, you will be downvoted into oblivion.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can ask a question on Stack Overflow about any computer programming language, domain-specific language, config language, or scripting language no matter how rare, esoteric, obscure or uninteresting.

We welcome all comers, but try to make it a good question :)

Comment: In general, *any* programming/scripting/markup/query language is OK. Examples include (but are not limited to): C, Ruby, HTML, CSS, SQL, [Dog](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/dog/info), and [Excel formulae](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261875/4200092). However, I'd add a couple of caveats: (A) Languages such as XML or JSON are [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) if they're simply being used to store a config file for a game or similar **i.e. there's no programming aspect to the question** (B) Batch files or bash scripts must be **non-trivial** i.e. involve loops/variables/etc.

Comment: It looks like you've made up a load of random rules @GoBusto, and then linked to a resource to back you up that doesn't mention anything like what you've said.

Comment: @Ben I'm not sure I understand? The various languages I listed are on-topic unless I'm very much mistaken (if so, please explain why). As for the "caveats", I should probably expand: (A) Questions like "How do I enable DirectX 10 support on SomeGame?" would still be off-topic, even if the game used XML files to store its settings (B) Questions such as "How can I do X with ffmpeg?" are more suited to [Super User](http://superuser.com), and don't really become programming questions just because you're putting them in a single-line `.sh` file rather than typing them directly into a bash terminal.

Comment: @Ben: GoBusto is just slightly expanding on it having to be about programming.