# Setting a proper tag for the Shakespeare Programming Language related questions

Tags: discussion, support, tags, retag-request

Recently I've been writing some code in the Shakespeare Programming Language and I've been searching through the StackOverflow for SPL. I realised that there is no tag for this language. The problem is, that the `spl` tag is used for some `php` related questions:

> "SPL is a collection of PHP interfaces and classes that are meant to solve standard problems."

Since `spl` is quite a concrete tag, it would be pointless to extened the `spl` tag to cover the Shakespeare Programming Language questions as well.

On the other hand, the tag `shakespeare-programming-language` is too long - you simply cannot use such long tags.

At the moment, there is a tag with a `shakespeare` in its name: a JavaScript library called `shakespeare-text`.

Shakespeare Programming Language is quite a popular language what it comes to [esoteric programming languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Esoteric_programming_language) in contrast to a language mentioned in this question: [Questions about really rare languages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283229/questions-about-really-rare-languages). Additionally, there are [official references](http://shakespearelang.sourceforge.net) to the SPL. That's why I think there should exist a proper tag for this unpopular language.

Here is another question related to the problem:
[What tag to use for question in a new programming language?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283027/what-tag-to-use-for-question-in-a-new-programming-language)

All in all my question is: **what is the StackOverflow community policy on such cases**.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Tread carefully.** Here be dragons.

First, [finding qualified questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=shakespeare+programming+is%3Aquestion) will be more involved than just using that incomplete search; they also have to be on-topic for the site overall.

Once you've found one that's on-topic, I'd recommend cleaning it up in any way that's necessary.

*Then*, and *only then*, should we discuss tagging.

My big issue is that the tag is incredibly small - likely will have only less than 10 questions in it.  But I don't necessarily see that as a prohibition to get it tagged.

So let's start with the work that needs to be done - find questions that are on-topic and start editing them if they require it.  Then, we could potentially use a tag like [shakespeare-lang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shakespeare-lang) to get the ball rolling.

Comment: Here are some questions edited by me waiting for the approval: 1. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1948372/compiling-and-executing-the-shakespeare-programming-language-translator-spl2c-on) 2. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18088870/shakespearean-programming-language)

Comment: If you're going to do this, don't forget to actually clean things up.  For the second one, only adding the tag didn't do it justice - it needed a bit of a visual layout overhaul and a proper title to go along with it.